# ubuntu: Cannot configuration mesh network

Tags: networking, wifi, wifi-hotspot

```
root@181RX:/home/pi/# iw phy
Wiphy phy0
        max # scan SSIDs: 4
        max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
        Retry short long limit: 2
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports RSN-IBSS.

        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x17e
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX Greenfield
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        No DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 32767 bytes (exponent: 0x002)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 2 usec (0x04)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7, 32
   ...
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        software interface modes (can always be added):
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ AP } <= 8,
                   total <= 8, #channels <= 1
        HT Capability overrides:
                 * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
                 * maximum A-MSDU length
                 * supported channel width
                 * short GI for 40 MHz
                 * max A-MPDU length exponent
                 * min MPDU start spacing
        Device supports TX status socket option.
        Device supports HT-IBSS.
        Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
        Device supports low priority scan.
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports AP scan.
        Device supports per-vif TX power setting
        Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
        Driver supports a userspace MPM
```

This is my wifi device 's property with `iw phy` command.
I need mesh configuration with this wifi dongle.
This is ralink rt3070 usb device.
Also, installed ubutnu os in nano pi.

```
root@181RX:/home/pi# iw dev $w interface add mesh0 type mp
```

> command failed: Operation not supported (-95)

My device is not support mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled mac80211 mesh via kernel configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, your device does not support 802.11s MESH. Otherwise your `iw list` output would look similar to this:

```
Supported interface modes:
  * IBSS
  * managed
  * AP
  * AP/VLAN
  * monitor
  * mesh point
```

Note **mesh point** at the bottom.